# correct way to populate angular7 select options with remote data?

Tags: angular, google-api, angular-material, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to load select options async from a remote source (Google calendar API).

I can load options remotely from a non-google source: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwhqzl)

But when I try to load from Google API, it doesn't render the options UNTIL I click the select dropdown OR I set the value (`FormControl.setValue()`) from a button click.

Why?  The only way I can get it to work is by calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` after calling `FormControl.setValue()`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkwzqg) is a stackblitz that shows the problem.

A few notes on the non-working stackblitz:

1. It requires you to login via Google, and grant my Client ID read access to your calendars.  You can look at my source and see I'm doing anything nefarious. You can also revoke access from your [google permissions page](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions), my App name is `ShiftCals`.
2. Open the `Console` in stackblitz. It will tell you when the select options (calendars) have been loaded from Google API.
3. To re-produce, click the login with google button, then wait for select box to show up.  It will be empty. Clicking on select or pressing `set 1st option` will force the select to re-render.
4. To re-run a test iteration, you need to reload the stackblitz preview frame.

My hunch is the problem is due to some timing issue, however I can't figure it out.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using on push?

Comment: hmm not sure what you mean - can you ask another way?

Comment: Can you please provide full source code of you component?

Comment: Is there a reason that you have `matNativeControl` on there rather than making the element a `mat-select` per the documentation. Also, can you confirm what version of Angular-Material you are using?

Comment: IMO its easer to select on mobile devices when using native select.   @angular/material 7.0.3.  I've updated my q. thanks

Comment: Simple solution would be just to call https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges.

Comment: I am not sure but I think issue is somewhere with async and ngZone

Comment: `this.ref.detectChanges();` did the trick, but that seems like a hack.  I agree it is probably some timing issue to do with async, however loading remote data for use in a select has to be a very common pattern.  I'm having trouble finding a clear example exercising this pattern.  You think if I make `calendarList` and Observable, and do `let cal of calendarList | async` it would work? My guess is no.

Comment: I'm drafting an answer, but have a few questions - why do you need to compareWith? Is it a multi selection? I definitely think you need the `async` on your `*ngFor`

Comment: thx in advance @nclarx.  Adding an ` | async` as it sits throws an error since `calendarList` is just plain ol JS list.  The docs suggest using compareWith when loading remote data.  Ex: I reload from remote, returned data doesn't change but angular doesn't know that. @see https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection . I'll work on a stackblitz example tomorrow if I can't figure this out fairly soon.

Comment: If you do a Stackblitz I'm happy to have a fiddle with it - i've got a similar thing I solved in one of my projects. Might be quicker than me providing something here that's off point. Drop a link in your qtn and i'll have a look at the Stackblitz

Comment: I re-factored to use Observable, and it still only works if `this.ref.detectChanges();` is called AFTER `this.calendarListControl.setValue()`.  SO frustrating.  I'll work on stackblitz tomorrow.

Comment: @nclarx I've added 2 stackblitzes.  1st working as I expected when loading from remote source, 2nd when loading via google API (not working).  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The answer lies in how Angular does change detection.  The [Zones in Angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) blog post explains it best, but in short, Angular relies on state changes (events, remote fetches etc) to initiate change detection.  These state changes are only monitored if they occur in the Angular Zone.

My stackblitz [with the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkwzqg), gets out of the zone because some of the Google JS (`gapi.load()`) runs in an iFrame - I think.  In either case, this is where the execution gets out of Angular's Zone.

[Here is the updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxefm2) with the implementation that works.

What I've done here is wrap the `gapi.load()` in a `Promise` who's context IS in the zone.  In addition, the `Promise`s resolution is an event that triggers Angular's change detection logic.

This was a tough one for an Angular novice like myself to track down, but I learned a lot.  If this topic interests you, [this blog post](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html), takes it a step further and talk's about making the painting performance even better.